# Why is the Ideal Norm Multiplicative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modules, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

I had asked this question before and got a partial answer.  Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain with quotient field $K$, $L$ a finite separable extension of $K$ of degree $n$, and $B$ the integral closure of $A$ in $L$.  The ideal norm $N_{L/K}$ is usually defined multiplicatively by the formula $N_{L/K}(\mathfrak P) = P^f$, where $P = \mathfrak P \cap A$ and $f = f(\mathfrak P / P)$.

Another way to define it is as follows: for fractional ideals $M$ and $N$ of $B$, the localizations $M_P$ and $N_P$ are free $A_P$-modules, so there is a $K$-module automorphism $\psi$ of $L$ for which $\psi(M_P) = N_P$.  One then defines the module index $[M_P : N_P]_{A_P}$ to be $Det(\psi)A$.  More generally one defines the module index $[M : N]_A$ to be $$ \prod\limits_P P^{\nu_P [M_P : N_P]_{A_P}}$$ If $M$ is a fractional ideal of $B$, one can define the norm $N_{L/K}(M)$ to be $[B : M]_A$.  (see Cassels and Frohlich, first section of Algebraic Number Theory)

I have seen a proof using Smith Canonical Form that these definitions agree when $M$ is a prime ideal, but I have yet to see a simple general proof that the norm (defined in the latter way) is multiplicative.  The "long" way of doing this is to look at the completions of $K$ with respect to the $\nu_P$, and then look at the ways in which $\nu_P$ may be extended to $L$ (which correspond to the prime ideals lying over $P$).  The special case $A = \mathbb{Z}$ is more clear, because the module index $[B : M]_{\mathbb{Z}}$ is just the ideal generated by the cardinality of $B/M$.

Comment: [Residue] Field extension degrees are multiplicative, and then from there you use multiplicativity from primes up to full ideals.

Answer (score 5):

Let me expand on my comment:

1) You use the CRT to reduce to the case of a prime power:  let

$$\mathfrak{a}=\prod_{i=1}^r\mathfrak{p_i}^{e_i}$$

with $\mathfrak{p}_i\ne\mathfrak{p}_j$ when $i\ne j$. Since each $\mathfrak{p_i}+\mathfrak{p_j}=\mathcal{O}$, we have

$$\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{a}\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^r\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}\;.$$

2) You use Krull dimension 1 to break down $\mathfrak{p}^{n+1}/\mathfrak{p}^n\cong\mathbb{F}_{N(\mathfrak{p})}$ to reduce to the case of prime ideals since you can measure the index of $[\mathcal{O}:\mathfrak{p}^e]$ using towers

$$\mathfrak{p}\stackrel{i_0}{\longrightarrow}\mathfrak{p}^2\stackrel{i_1}{\longrightarrow}\ldots\stackrel{i_e}{\longrightarrow}\mathfrak{p}^e$$

where each $i_k$ is inclusion.

3) From there you just need to measure the size of relative field extensions. If $\lambda/\kappa$ is the residue field extension for $L/K$, then $\lambda$ is a vector space over $\kappa$ as well as over the base field, $\mathbb{F}_p$. But then $[\lambda:\mathbb{F}_p]=[\lambda:\kappa][\kappa:\mathbb{F}_p]$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still not seeing it.  Where does the determinant come into play?  I'm aware that $B/ \mathfrak P^e$ has rank $e Rank(B/ \mathfrak P)$ as an $A/P$-module, but I don't see how it's relevant.  Where is the determinant of a linear transformation which maps $B_P$ to $\mathfrak P^e B_P$ coming in?

Comment: I'm not making reference to the determinant anywhere, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: This approach is meant to break things down into three steps, each of which is multiplicative and bootstrap up to full multiplicativity. Just as one is loath to prove all polynomials are continuous when it is easier to prove monomials are and then bootstrap up by proving sums of continuous functions are continuous. The philosophy is the same.

Comment: Well okay, but what exactly did you prove then? I want to show that the norm defined in the nonstandard way was multiplicative (then once you show both norms agree on prime ideals then they must be the same).

Comment: Your question doesn't ask that. It just outlines the different ways and the title says "why is the ideal norm multiplicative?" Are you interested in a particular equivalence?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being very clear.  What I'm looking for is a proof that if $M$ and $N$ are fractional ideals, then $$[B : MN]_A = [B : M]_A [B : N]_A$$

Comment: I think I'm also a bit confused then:  once you prove it for integral ideals, the rest is a formality of the group structure on $J(\mathcal{O})$.

Comment: I have yet to even prove it for integral ideals.  I have seen a proof that if $\mathfrak P$ is a prime ideal lying over $P$, then $$[B : \mathfrak P]_A = P^{f(\mathfrak P/P)}$$ (given here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631574/equivalent-definitions-of-ideal-norm?rq=1).  Frohlich's section of A.N.T. sketches how to show multiplicativity of $[B : -]_A$, but leaves out most of the details and the sketch is very topological/analytical.  I was hoping to find a simpler (preferably purely algebraic) proof that $[B : -]_A$ is multiplicative.

Comment: OK, well there we go. The steps I outline above are a proof for integral ideals. You start with the definition as indices, use the CRT to reduce to prime powers, show it's multiplicative for prime powers, then show that it's multiplicative for prime extensions by looking at vector space dimensions.

Comment: Your argument with the Chinese Remainder Theorem is applicable when $[B : M]_A$ is generated by the group index $[B : M]$, but for arbitrary Dedekind domains we don't know this index is finite.  All we know is that $B/ \mathfrak P$ is a finite extension of $A/P$.  The function $[B : -]_A$ is defined locally in terms of a determinant, not in terms of a rank over a field, and I don't understand how this definition fits in to what you are saying.  I'm sorry to trouble you with these concerns, but this question has been tripping me up for months on end and I am anxious to finally understand it.

Comment: I mean, one can do this with determinants as well, yes. That's usually Serre's approach, which I can outline if you like, but Dedekind domains are characterized by unique ideal factorization. If any index is finite you will get infinite index for anything with that prime in its factorization, so you may as well just consider finite index. In particular, you were asking for an "easy" way to see things, which is hardly the case with the determinant approach.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I would love to see an outline of the ideal norm's multiplicativity using determinants if you know how to do it.

Comment: @D_S if you want to ask that in a separate question, I'd be happy to address it, but I think this one has already blown out of proportion with all the comments. I think you should mark this question as complete first, but the determinant thing is quite easily established.

Comment: I cannot mark this question as complete, because it has not yet been answered.  What I was asking for was a proof that the ideal norm is multiplicative when defined in terms of the determinant.